# What Power Steering Fluid to use with a 99 Nissan Almera?

Tags: nissan, power-steering

What power steering fluid should be used with a 1999 N15 Nissan Almera GX 1.6L GA16DE engine?  I've read that many modern vehicles can't use ATF and need specific fluids specified by the manufacturer.

I just found this site which sells fluid and lets you look them up by model and it lists the 1.6L 99 Almera [as using ATF for steering fluid](http://www.europarts-motorfactors.com/lubricants-fluids/steering-fluids/Nissan/Almera/all/1.6/1999/Parts.aspx).

Can I trust this site and is there more than one type of ATF?

Comment: Can you please let us know your engine size (e.g. 1.4L) and the model code of the Almera - e.g. N15

Comment: @Nick Please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that ATF should work just fine. That is what is specified for the vehicle.